# Is there a word “vinnana” in Sanskrit?

Tags: words

I have come across a word “vinnana “ while studying Pali language Suttas.
Pali is based on Sanskrit. Sanskrit is a Hindu religious language.

My question is : Is there a word “vinnana “ in Sanskrit?

Comment: There is a word 'viññāṇa' (विञ्ञाण) which is a Pāli equivalent of the Sanskrit term 'vijñāna' (विज्ञान).
You can look up Pali dictionary here https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?page=619